# Is there an end event when using the request module?

Tags: json, node.js, request

I am using the request module that found on npm, and I am wondering if there is an end event that i can bind to. The reason i'm asking is because i am requesting a JSON and i am getting an error if i try to use JSON.parse directly after i get the response.  The code looks something like this.

```
var parseJSON = function(JSON, cb){

    var parsed = JSON.parse(JSON);
    cb(parsed);

};

request(url, function(error, response, body) {

    parseJSON(body, function(bodyObj){

        // do stuff with bodyObj...

    });
});
```

Trying to do this, gives the following error...

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(JSON);
                  ^
has no method 'parse'
    at parseJSON (/home/stephen/Desktop/redditjs/reddit.js:31:20)
    at Requester.collector [as _callback] (/home/stephen/Desktop/redditjs/reddit.js:43:5)
    at Request.init.self.callback (/home/stephen/node_modules/request/main.js:122:22)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:99:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/stephen/node_modules/request/main.js:661:16)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
    at IncomingMessage.Request.start.self.req.self.httpModule.request.buffer (/home/stephen/node_modules/request/main.js:623:14)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
    at IncomingMessage._emitEnd (http.js:366:10)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnMessageComplete [as onMessageComplete] (http.js:149:23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're overriding the global JSON object.

This will work just fine:

```
var parseJSON = function(MyJSON, cb){

    var parsed = JSON.parse(MyJSON);
    cb(parsed);

};
```